# How to display private (or draft) Wordpress blog post outside blog

Tags: php, wordpress, api, codex

I would like WordPress to use as a edit tool and my website as a renderer, but don't want to posts created for website display on my blog. So I did this on my website:

- created private post
- put on website this:

  define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
  require('blog/wp-load.php');

  $args = array(
      'post_status'      => 'private',
      'p'    => '3019'
  );
  query_posts( $args );

  ?>

Unfortunately it does not work.

When i set p to post id that is published it works.
When i publish my private post as public it works too.
But when post is private it does not work.

What to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use get_posts would be easier.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts